# looking for HTML tutorials

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Does anyone know the type of scrolling used in these websites? http://www.mimochai.com/ and http://www.jennetliaw.com/#design. Where you get that sliding effect when you scroll down. I'm looking for the terminology but can't find if there's a word to describe it.

Comment: I've seen a lot of one-pagers done in wordpress templates, and I believe they're called parallax websites. Use your google machine.

Comment: @9Deuce I've been googling for the past hour for a word to describe that type of scrolling. And yes parallax websites, Just the word I was looking for haha!! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm going to drop it below as an answer since it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of website you're looking for is called a Parallax site. They're common on Wordpress.